# Why Ingress NGINX removes my response headers

Tags: nginx, asp.net-web-api, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have ASP.NET WebApi project, which return security headers on each request:

[image]

When I run this app in Kubernetes cluster with Ingress NGINX, my headers are missed

[image]

How I can configure NGINX to use response headers from my application? Why Ingress NGINX removes my response headers?

I don't have any experience with NGINX configuration. Please suggest how to do that in k8s cluster. Thanks

Comment: can you ensure your nginx-controller use this configmap you created?

Comment: Yes, it is in use. Because when I add "server-tokens": "false" to it, Server header is gone.

Comment: I don't think the response goes through the ingress controller. Your backends are nginx too?

Answer (score 11):

Use following annotations in your ingress to set response header

```
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      more_set_headers "X-Frame-Options: Deny";
      more_set_headers "X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block";
      more_set_headers "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff";
```

Comment: Is there any possibility to use headers from my application? I have many ingresses, I can't set this for every of them

Comment: My app has already returns headers that I need, why nginx remove it?

Answer (score 1):

The you are not able to find those headers as the traffic is flowing from a nginx ingress controller which acts as a proxy. To add some custom headers you can use the following given steps.

1. create a file and name it as `custom-headers.yml` and add the following data.

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   data:
     X-Frame-Options: "Deny"
     X-Xss-Protection: "1; mode=block"
     X-Content-Type-Options: "nosniff"
     kind: ConfigMap
   metadata:
   name: custom-headers
   namespace: ingress-nginx
   ```

This file will create a ConfigMap in the ingress-nginx namespace. Apply this ConfigMap:
`kubectl apply -f custom-headers.yml`

Now we need to make our nginx ingress controller to use this new ConfigMap. For that we need to add our config map with the global configs that were being used until now. For that create a file configmap.yml and add the following data.
        apiVersion: v1
        data:
          proxy-set-headers: "ingress-nginx/custom-headers"
        kind: ConfigMap
        metadata:
          name: nginx-configuration
          namespace: ingress-nginx
          labels:
            app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
            app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx

Apply this configuration by :
`kubectl apply -f configmap.yml`

Check your configurations by using : `kubectl exec <nginx-controller pod name> -n ingress-nginx cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

Comment: this works only for input requests, I need to add response headers

Answer (score 0):

If your headers contain underscores you need to enable this option in NGNIX

`enable-underscores-in-headers: true`

Answer (score -1):

I have not tried this myself but I think you need to enable this setting.

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#allow-backend-server-header

```
data:
    allow-backend-server: "true"
```

You may try to enable this settings via annotations.

Comment: Be careful with "I have not tried" answers. Some people here recommendably sacrifice their time to test proposed answers. Some do the same thing maliciously. Both kinds tend to downvote non-working untested answers. Some downvote untested answers - working or not.

Comment: @Yunnosch  Thankyou for your suggestion which lead to new point of view. I ve never thoughts abt this before this reply.

Comment: This seem to only affect the `Server` header looking at the documentation...